# how to fix this imageview error?

Tags: android, imageview

Allow me to explain. I have :

1. a button with picture (located at @drawable/pic),
2. linear layout (id=linear1)

the button xml is below :

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/pic"
            android:maxWidth="80dp"
            android:maxHeight="80dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

the linear layout xml is as follow :

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:ignore="UselessLeaf" >
```

what i want is, when i click the button i want to create/generate imageview programatically inside the linearlayout and i want to fill it with the same picture for the button (pic). The code is below :

```
//initiate imageview
    ImageView img=new ImageView(this);
    //get drawable from button
    Drawable blabla=btn1.getDrawable();

    //set drawable to imageview
    img.setImageDrawable(blabla);

    //set height and width of imageview to 50dp 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);
    img.setLayoutParams(parms);
    img.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

    //place imageview to linearlayout 
    layoutTempat.addView(img);
```

The code works fine with displaying the imageview with the same image as the button have.
however the problem is : **when i set the imageview to 50dp programatically, the image inside button changed too..** how can it happened ? i am so confused as iam a newbie..

Thanks before.

Comment: I encourted same problem some time before and decided to stick with, ImageView + Button combination since offers more flexibility. I think that thing that you encourted is the way they wanted it to be displayed.

Comment: How does the button change! ?

Comment: It might help if you had something visual to describe the effect you want. Also, `new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50);` that's 50 pixels, *not* dp. If you are going to create LayoutParams programmatically like this, then you need to multiply this by the density scale factor of the screen.

Comment: Put your initialization code for the layout and the button image

Comment: guys, thank you.. someone below has answered this problem prefectly..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two views are sharing the same drawable.

It's plausible your manipulations on one view are being sent to the underlying drawable, effecting how its displayed in the other view -- frankly I don't know.  But assuming the case is as you described, this problem is easily fixed by cloning the drawable as follows:

```
Drawable dr = btn1.getDrawable().getConstantState().newDrawable();
img.setImageDrawable(dr);
```

Comment: Hy thanks !,, this is the ultimate answer apparently . . but i found a new way as well :

**it seem that if i change the button properties 'scaletype' into 'cropcenter', not 'fitxy' the program is worked as i wanted.**